# Totals at the bottom of this crosstab query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below query.

Is there a way there can be a Grand Total on the last row summing up all the columns? I.e. for the Total, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday columns.

```
SELECT Format(onhour, '00') + ':00' AS Hour, 
       Sum(totals)                  AS Total, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Monday'    THEN totals END) AS Monday  , 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Tuesday'   THEN totals END) AS Tuesday , 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Wednesday' THEN totals END) AS Wednesday, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Thursday'  THEN totals END) AS Thursday, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Friday'    THEN totals END) AS Friday  , 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Saturday'  THEN totals END) AS Saturday, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Sunday'    THEN totals END) AS Sunday
FROM   (SELECT Datename(weekday, D.fordate) AS DayOfWeek, 
               H.onhour, 
               Isnull(T.totals, 0)          AS Totals 
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT T.fordate 
                FROM   #visit AS T) AS D 
               CROSS apply (VALUES(0), 
                                  (1), 
                                  (2), 
                                  (3), 
                                  (4), 
                                  (5), 
                                  (6), 
                                  (7), 
                                  (8), 
                                  (9), 
                                  (10), 
                                  (11), 
                                  (12), 
                                  (13), 
                                  (14), 
                                  (15), 
                                  (16), 
                                  (17), 
                                  (18), 
                                  (19), 
                                  (20), 
                                  (21), 
                                  (22), 
                                  (23)) AS H(onhour) 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN #visit AS T 
                            ON H.onhour = T.onhour 
                               AND D.fordate = T.fordate) a 
WHERE  onhour NOT IN ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 
                       4, 5, 6, 7, 
                       20, 21, 22, 23 ) 
GROUP  BY onhour 
ORDER  BY onhour;
```

Comment: This is like the 3rd variation of this question. Did you get the other questions resolved? Just wondering so many posts of the similar query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Use `grouping sets`:

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (onhour), () )
```

You may want to change the `ORDER BY` to:

```
ORDER BY GROUPING(onhour), onhour
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it sums up the Totals column properly, but on the other columns, it seems to average it again?

Comment: @Philip . . . Yes, the result is based on the aggregation function used for the original calculation.

Comment: I see ... is it possible to total them up instead some how ?